# Javascript GUI like Yahoo Pipes

Tags: javascript, ria, yahoo-pipes

I want to develop a GUI like Yahoo Pipes.

Can anyone suggest some library or framework?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was about to ask this same question whenever I came across an awesome library myself. I know this response is way late, but hopefully it will help others looking for a similar resource.

The library is called WireIt and is released under the MIT license.

[WireIt Library](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/)

Answer (score 5):

jsPlumb is also a great library for "yahoo pipes"-like GUI:[http://www.jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html](http://www.jsplumb.org). You can use it with mootools, jquery or YUI. It works on SVG, Canvas or VML. iIt does not include forms but I guess you can open one with some attached event on connectors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: Seems not supporting latest IE